# How to empty object from records

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to triggers and trying to understand them.
I got the part before and after.  I came accros the following trigger which is supose te delete alle records from the AccountTemp__c object which is not the case.s All records are being saved on the object see:

```
trigger AccountTempTrigger on AccountTemp__c(before insert, before update, after insert, after update, before delete, after delete) {
  AccountTempUtil.entry(new TriggerParams(trigger.isBefore, trigger.isAfter, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isDelete,
                              trigger.isUndelete, trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap));
}
```

The part which confuses me is

```
AccountTempUtil.entry(new TriggerParams(trigger.isBefore, trigger.isAfter, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isDelete,
                              trigger.isUndelete, trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap));
```

Doesnt this part mean that all records are being preserved by  `trigger.isUndelete` and `trigger.old`? I couldn't get any info on `new TriggerParams`.

Comment: You should have classes in your org called `TriggerParams` and `AccountTempUtil`. All the logic is there.

Comment: It looks like you're using a trigger framework here. While that is generally a good idea (to use a trigger framework), that's just one more layer of abstraction/complication that you're trying to understand here.  If you're not experienced with triggers, I might suggest _not_ trying to use a framework for a while.

Comment: What the heck does your title have to do with the body of this question? What is it you are trying to achieve? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at trigger context variables, which means that the trigger  will run the logic in any of the contexts: before insert, before update, after insert, after update, before delete, after delete.  A comprehensive list of trigger context variables can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

You will not find information on TriggerParams as it is a variable name and not a trigger context.